# net::ERR_ABORTED 500 when loading in script tag (Hybris)

Tags: javascript, html, widget, sap-commerce-cloud, zk

I want to load js file from my project folder in my zul page but it gives me this net::ERR_ABORTED 500 error.

zul file

```html
    <html>
        <h:head>

            <script defer="true" type="text/javascript" src="${wr}/graphConfiguration.js"/>

        </h:head>
```

hybris custom widget folder tree [image]

Comment: Can you post the whole zul file ? I don't really understand why you have htlm and header tag inside a widget to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 means a server internal error. It's caused by a server side problem. I think you should check server log to see if there is any exception.

please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500?retiredLocale=id

BTW, the correct way to put script in `<head>` is to use https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML%20Reference/ZUML/Processing%20Instructions/script